# How can I run all methods of a class on Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I've created a Swing component which has several methods.  I want all methods of this class be run on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), while callers are on Worker threads. The only solution currently in my mind is this:

For each method in this class:

```
public void a(params)
```

I should rename it to:

```
private void aOnEDT(params)
```

and add another method:

```
public void a(params) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            aOnEDT(params);
        }
    });
}
```

But isn't this nasty? How should I do this?

Comment: The question is why do you suddenly invoke these methods? Generally code is executed when some event occurs on the GUI, like an ActionEvent or a mouse click. If this is the case then the code will execute on the EDT automatically by default. If you have some other logic that invokes these methods, then only the origianl method need to be wrapped in an invokeLater(). All

Comment: There's a worker thread with a long lasting job(copying files), and it informs listeners about happenings:success, failure, progress etc. My component is one of the listeners, so several methods of my component will be called by worker thread.

Answer (score 3):

You could test whether the call is currently being made on the EDT or not, and drop a `Runnable` into `SwingUtilites.invokeLater()` if it isnt:

```
public void myMethod() {
       if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            //... your code
       } else {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                  new Runnable(){
                     public void run() {
                           myMethod();
                     }
                  });
       {
  }
```

This will keep the method running if it you are on the EDT, without putting it to the end of the event queue.

Comment: Hmm, nice way to make sure the method is executed on the EDT.

Comment: This is very good to use when developing your program, but in the long run you should not rely on this and instead realize which calls are already on the EDT and which aren't--this adds a lot of mess and--I hate to mention performance but a significant overhead if it's done a lot (like a few hundred times a second or more).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want something to execute on the Event Dispatch Thread, you should use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun)`](http://tinyurl.com/9kqr5).

Extract from the Javadoc:

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed
>   asynchronously on the AWT event
>   dispatching thread. This will happen
>   after all pending AWT events have been
>   processed. This method should be used
>   when an application thread needs to
>   update the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

In all of the methods you need to run on the EDT you should wrap the method body in the following code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){


    // All code placed in here will be ran asynchronously on the EDT


}});
```

This will cause all things in the method to be ran on the EDT.  Because you are running code on the EDT, you should not be doing anything that will block for a long time. (File IO, long computations, etc)  Otherwise your GUI will freeze and become unresponsive.

[`invokeLater()` javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Thank you for your response. Isn't there any solution that works for all methods without changing all of current and upcoming methods?

Comment: @mhosenof I could not think of one.  This is the best solution I could think of.  If you format it like I did, it is only 2 extra lines.

Comment: @mohsenof It is not usually the case that someone wants every method to run on the EDT because it could cause your GUI to run slowly if too many things happen on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and update your GUI-Components in the done() method. Do the background work in the donInBackground() method.

Comment: From his question, it seems he is already using worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

One way we accomplished that is using AspectJ. The boilerplate code is injected during compilation into all methods annotated with @OnEDT. Resulting code is slim and very convenient.

Obliviously we had to create the annotation, pointcut and aspect for that, but that was almost trivial.

Here are few related links if you're interested:

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/

http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/EclipseCon2006/

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~mdeters/doc/slides/aspectjtutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your responses.
Finally we (well, just my friend not me!) created a wrapper class around our component. This wrapper receives all calls, creates a runnable (inside run() we call actual method) and send this runnable to invokeLater().
All of this seems to be not so complicated using reflection library.
The starting point is java.lang.reflect.Proxy class which dynamically creates an instance of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the "nastiness" from existing inside every single method of your class, if your class implements a public interface, you could use a [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to perform the common `invokeAndWait` setup separate from where you implement the methods themselves.

1. Implement a Proxy [InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) that would deal with all the boilerplate code to check for the event dispatch thread and call `invokeAndWait`
2. Create an instance of the proxy and call methods on it, instead of directly on your implementation class.

Since this approach includes more code overall up-front, it's really only suitable if your implementation class has a large number of methods that you want to ensure run on the EDT.

Full example:

```
public class ImplClass implements ClassInterface {
    public void a( String paramA, int paramB ) {
        // do something here...
    }
}

public interface ClassInterface {
    void a( String paramA, int paramB );
}

public class MyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private ClassInterface implClassInstance;
    public MyHandler( ImplClass implInstance ) {
        this.implClassInstance = implInstance;
    }
    public Object invoke( Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args ) throws Throwable {
        if( SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() ) {
            method.invoke( implClassInstance, args );
        }
        else {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        method.invoke( implClassInstance, args );
                    }
                    catch( RuntimeException e ) {
                        throw e;
                    }
                    catch( Exception e ) {
                        throw new RuntimeException( e );
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's how you would use the proxy:

```
// create the proxy like this:
ImplClass implInstance = new ImplClass();
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler(implInstance);
ClassInterface proxy = (ClassInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance( this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] { ClassInterface.class }, handler );
// ...
// call the proxy like you would an instance of your implementation class
proxy.a( "paramAValue", 123 );
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it won't run because  the Java 1.7/8 awt class loader throws a SecurityException  if you try to load a class with a "java.awt" package :(
  Using a different package mangles the required interfaces.